# Ubuntu boot failed and Windows Boot Manager boot failed

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I had Ubuntu 17.10 installed beside Windows 10 and all things were working normally. I deleted the Ubuntu partition then the windows partition and finally formatted the hard disk. Now when I open the laptop it shows "Ubuntu boot failed" message and then "Windows Boot Manager boot failed" and shows this screen.

[image]

How to solve this problem? I want to install Ubuntu again without any problem

Comment: IF you deleted all the partitions, there is nothing to boot. You need to boot Ubuntu live installer & reinstall Ubuntu. If UEFI system be sure to boot flash drive in UEFI mode to get it to install in UEFI boot mode. UEFI has NVRAM, so it should still show the old boot entries which have nothing to boot on hard drive.

Comment: I tried to reinstall ubuntu using a USB stick and a CD...when I enter the boot menu it shows up the boot from usb and from cd options but they aren't working and give the boot failed message...I tried to change boot mode from bios menu from legacy to UEFI but nothing happened and it returned to the legacy option again automatically

Comment: You may have to have UEFI set to on in UEFI. Is this same install flash drive you used before? Else confirm that downloaded ISO is good and flash drive is still good. It may change flash drive to BIOS/Legacy boot if that is what you choose in UEFI. You should have two entries to boot flash drive, one UEFI and one not.

Comment: i used the same flash drive and a different one and different downloaded ISO and nothing happened...I even restored the bios defaults and tried removing and putting again the CMOS battery but nothing happened the laptop still showing boot failed and windows failed and boot in legacy mood only

Comment: Removing battery resets most things in UEFI to defaults. So you may need to go back and turn off UEFI Secure boot and turn on allow USB boot. Not sure what other settings your system may need, some need multiple settings. What brand & model system?

Comment: it is Lenovo Ideapad y50-70

Comment: It looks like it has nVIdia, so you need nomodeset, by editing grub boot stanza, replace quiet splash with nomodeset. Screen shot of where you edit grub in this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: just to be clear the system doesn't stop at the message screen I mentioned in the topic....if I connected a USB with Ubuntu or Windows it enter to the installation but in legacy mode

Comment: You need UEFI on, but UEFI secure boot off. Some have UEFI or CSM/Legacy/BIOS setting which need to be UEFI. But the choice of booting flash drive is usually still separate. You have to choose UEFI:flash drive to boot in UEFI mode & then install in UEFI mode.

Comment: when I enter the boot menu using F12 it shows the boot from usb option I choose it I get the message "EFI usb device boot failed"

Comment: Then USB boot device not correctly configured or bad  download of ISO from Ubuntu. http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb

Comment: I think there is nothing wrong with the usb....Is there any method to delete the ubuntu boot option and windows from wherever they are stored in the laptop ? obviously they aren't stored on the hard disk because I already formatted

Comment: Typically formatting does not erase UEFI NVRAM if UEFI or if BIOS may not have erased MBR. But that has nothing to do with not being able to boot flash drive. If you remove UEFI entries, then when flash drive does not work, it just will give UEFI boot error. You may be able to remove UEFI entries in UEFI directly, but otherwise you have to boot something: https://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi

Comment: efibootmgr gives this error "efibootmgr: efi variables are not supported on this system"

Comment: Then you have booted in BIOS/CSM/Legacy mode, not UEFI boot mode.

Comment: Because I used sata hdd from the boot option....because it is the only working option and the other shows boot failed message...and I can't change the bios menu from legacy to UEFI because it doesn't save changes except the clock

Comment: Do you have latest UEFI from vendor for your system? It sounds like you have lots of UEFI system issues. But also some UEFI need various settings changed. Unless this is an old system you updated from Windows 7 to Windows 10. Windows 7 systems usually were BIOS/MBR, but some newer Windows 7 systems had early UEFI as vendors were just starting to use UEFI.